# How to debug php-xdebug x NetBeans8.2 x POSTman in an external income request by POST?

Tags: post, netbeans, xdebug

I have a file called `postback.php`. This file will receive requests by POST from a credit card company for example.

For now, I am able to send the XML to postback.php through [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) and I can debug adding some `die();` AND `echo` as stop points, that will be displayed in postman.

But I would like to track the whole process as an regular xdebug session, step by step.

how can I achieve that?